# Why customized title header of the List Views web part does not reflect correctly for other users?

Tags: 2007, xslt, column

I used the SharePoint Designer 2007 to generate the XSLT Data View and made modification to the column headers.

Although I am able to see the new column header's name, other users still are not able to see the new column header's name. Instead, other users still see the old column header name.

What could be missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you forgot to check-in your site page in SharePoint and its still checked-out by your user.

you can quickly browse that page from browser >> site actions >> edit page
and then see ribbon icon next to 'save & close'.

Comment: I generate the XSLT on the List View in a aspx file. I have checked that the aspx file is not checked out in the first place. So, I was wondering why the changes is not reflected.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Page Library have versioning enabled? Make sure that the page on which you put your web part is checked in and published.

Same is the case if you have stored the XSLT in the Style Library. Make sure it is checked in and published.

Comment: I generate the XSLT on the List View in a aspx file. I have checked that the aspx file is not checked out in the first place. So, I was wondering why the changes is not reflected.

Comment: Is audience targeting set on the webpart?

Comment: No, the audience targeting is not set on the webpart.

Comment: I also notice that those user that created the forms and have their forms inside the library will have the the correct title. Those user without forms will not able to see the new column header's name

Answer (score 0):

I would have tried to clear browser cache on client machines of other users.  This depends on browser and Windows but easily searchable on Internet